# Unable to start RabbitMQ server on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I am trying to start my RabbitMQ server using the command

`sudo service rabbitmq-server start`

The failure message shown as below

> Starting message broker rabbitmq-server FAILED - check
>   /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}

The entry in the error file is shown as follows:

> erlexec: Error 13 executing
>   '/usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4/bin/beam.smp'.

Please kindly let me your suggestions to resolve this error

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Error 13 is "Permission denied". You should double-check Erlang is correctly installed. For instance, if you run `erl`, do you get a working Erlang shell?